# Tail-call optimization in recursive equations

Tags: python, optimization, tail-recursion

I have the following two mutually recursive functions,

[image: Where]

Since Python doesn't handle tail-call optimization well, the programmer should represent these functions as stateful loops. What techniques does the Python community use to transform this kind of equation into explicit loops?

Or are these transformations algorithm-dependent and each recursive function must be analyzed separately?

**Recursive implementation**:

Let `C1 = xpa, C2 = p and C3 = xpb` then

```
def obaraSaika(p,s00x,i,j,xpa,xpb):

    if i < 0 or j < 0: return 0

    if i == 0 and j == 0: return s00x

    if i >= 1: return xpa*(obaraSaika(p,s00x,i-1,j,xpa,xpb)) + \
               p*((i-1)*(obaraSaika(p,s00x,i-2,j)) + j*(obaraSaika(p,s00x,i-1,j-1,xpa,xpb) ) )

    if j >= 1: return xpb*(obaraSaika(p,s00x,i-1,j,xpa,xpb)) + \
               p*(i * (obaraSaika(p,s00x,i-1,j-1)) + (j-1)*(obaraSaika(p,s00x,i,j-2,xpa,xpb) ) )
```

The idea of this implementation is to traverse the tree using firstly the `i` index, and then once `i == 0`, reduce the tree using the `j` index.

Comment: Did you already implement it recursively in python. I guess this is a good starting point for the *python community*: please show us the same in python syntax.

Comment: BTW: I see only one function, `S`, with two parameters. Am I wrong?

Comment: And I see several recursive calls, so tail-call optimization wouldn't help much anyway. I don't know how these functions behave, but if they're called a lot with the same parameters you could memoize (cache) them?

Comment: While `S(0,0)` seems to be well-defined (BTW: how exactly?), I see a lack of definition for `S(i-1,j)` and `S(i,j-1)`.

Comment: That `if i < 0 or j < 0: return 0` is an important point! And also this `if i == 0 and j == 0: return s00x` here is where programming can start :-)

Comment: These are the standard equation to calculate a value in chemistry, I have implemented them in Haskell but I'm not sure how to approach them in python

Comment: The last part seem to be misindented? Fixed.

Comment: FYI [Google:Obara-Saika](http://www.google.com/search?q=Obara-Saika)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich in my Haskell implementation I used a memoization monad to cache the values, but I first want to transform this equation to a stateful loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming any recursive algorithm into a non-recursive equivalent is simple.

When you perform a recursive call, what you're actually doing is pushing a set of arguments onto a stack. This stack is provided to you by the Python interpreter.

So, the way you rewrite the algorithm without recursion is... you manage the stack yourself! When you would make a recursive call, instead you take all the arguments you would have passed and push them onto your stack object. Then you have a "driver" loop that repeatedly pops off the stack and does the computation listed therein.

The signature of this type of program is that there's one stack object, which you prime with an initial state tuple/object, and then a `while len(stack) > 0` loop that runs until you're finished.

You basically do just what the recursion would do, but when you manage the relevant data structures yourself it gives you a better opportunity for efficiency gains.

This particular type of transformation works for any algorithm. Others, specifically those involving carrying global state across different calls to the function(s) in question, are algorithm-dependent.

Comment: A tiny illustrating example would help to understand this technique.

Comment: @Wolf Here's a pretty good example in Javascript: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/08/01/recursion-part-two-unrolling-a-recursive-function-with-an-explicit-stack.aspx